# How to store array of modal iOS

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

In my application,

I have one `NSMutableArray` which contains modal objects, I want to store this array in `NSUserDefaults`.

When i try to store and retrieves it returns me nil values.
After doing some research i found we can't store objects in `NSUserDefaults`.

Is there any alternative and easy way to store?

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: You can store custom object in NSUserDefaults

Comment: show your code that you have tried!

Answer (score 1):

Store custom objects of class in `NSMutableArray`. Archive that array using `<NSCoding>`Protocol and then store it in `NSUserDefaults`.:
[check this link](https://soffes.blog/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding)

Comment: This should be comment instead of answer!